# JPA identifier of an instance was altered from 'X' to null

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

### Issue

This is my first time working with JPA. I have 2 entities: `Component` and `Manufacturer`, which are in `ManyToOne` relation. The Manufacturer's ID is the foreign key in Component. Only the foreign key should be deleted. When I try to set a component's ID to null and save it, the following exception occurs:

```java
"identifier of an instance of spring.model.Manufacturer was altered
 from 1 to null; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an 
instance of spring.model.Manufacturer was altered from 1 to null",
```

### ER Diagram

[image]

### Models

#### BaseEntity

```java
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;
}
```

#### Component

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Components")
public class Component extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double price;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 2048)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer rating;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturerId")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
}
```

#### Manufacturer

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Manufacturers")
public class Manufacturer extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer foundingYear;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double revenue;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manufacturer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Component> components = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

### Current code

```java
@DeleteMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void deleteComponentManufacturer(@PathVariable("componentId") Long id) {
    Optional<Component> component = componentDao.findById(id);
    if (component.isEmpty()) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Could not delete component's (ID: " + id + ") manufacturer");
    }
    if (component.get().getManufacturer() == null) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Component with ID: " + id + " has no manufacturer");
    }
    component.get().getManufacturer().setId(null);
     componentDao.save(component.get());              // Error is thrown here
}
```

Comment: Every column in a database needs a primary key. We cannot `null` this column. --- What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want to remove the link from a `Component` to a `Manufacturer`? If so, `component.setManufaturer(null)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the manufacturer's id from whatever it was to `null` here:

```
component.get().getManufacturer().setId(null);
```

When you call `.getManufacturer()` you are getting the actual entity linked to the record in the *manufacturer* table. When you call `.setId(null)` on that object, you are modifying the manufacturer.

I suspect what you are *trying* to do is disassociate the component from the manufacturer, so that on the *component* record, the `manufacturerid` is null. To do that, you need this:

```
component.get().setManufacturer(null);
```